# On the notion of set equality.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations

I should start by providing some context. I want to understand the foundations of mathematics and in doing so have been looking at different texts involving ZF set theory and category theory. I understand that set theory takes the view that every mathematical object is to be described as a set. I don't have a problem with that, but I've seen in the past that when others (usually as new to the subject as me) try to ask questions on the foundations of set theory and look for alternatives to doing mathematics, the questions are often met with a response of the form 'why would one want to get rid of set theory?'. That's not my intention. I just want to see if there are precise descriptions of terms like 'object', 'rule' and 'equality' outside of it that one can talk about rigorously without using sets to define them.

I'm currently looking at the notions of equality in set theory. We define sets to be equal when they have the same elements.

Basically, we can say that $A = B$ if and only if for every $x \in A$ we have $x \in B$ and for every $x \in B$ we have $x \in A$.

Now we are using $x$ as a symbol representing arbitrary elements of $A$ and $B$, so suppose that the definition holds true and $A$ and $B$ are equal but using set notation we have $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and $B =\{d,e,f\}$. In order for you to be able to say that $A$ and $B$ are equal, you have to be able to provide some means through which you can say things like $a = d$. In other words, it seems to me that you need rules which say the objects themselves are equal prior to being able to define notions of set equality.

It seems to me that if you say, $a$ and $d$ are sets, then you can continue asking about how equality is defined for the elements of $a$ and $d$ indefinitely until you run into some kind of object that isn't a set or the empty set.

My question therefore is this: do we have a way of talking about mathematics that deals with 'rules' on 'mathematical objects' directly in order to define some form of equality? And can such a way of talking about mathematics be used at the foundations in a rigorous way alongside the notion of sets? For a simple example, maybe the rule is addition and the objects are numbers. Only in the context of such a rule can we say the set $\{2 + 2, 3 + 4\}$ is equal to the set $\{4,7\}$. However, without such a rule, they must be treated as different sets. The idea of numbers and addition being sets themselves doesn't have to be removed, but I would rather treat them as 'examples' of objects with a 'number-like' property and an 'addition-like' property that has been defined prior to constructing them with sets.

Comment: "In other words, it seems to me that you need rules which say the objects themselves are equal prior to being able to define notions of set equality."
I believe that in ZFC, equality is assumed to be a primitive notion in predicate logic and so is not given a definition.  So the fact that sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements (the Axiom of Extension) is not giving the **definition** of equality, but rather, asserting that there are certain conditions that **imply** equality.

Comment: Compare to, e.g., the definition of an antisymmetric relation $R$: if $x R y$ and $y R x$ then $x = y$.  This is not giving a definition of $x=y$.  It's saying that if your relation $R$ doesn't satisfy this condition, it's not antisymmetric.  Similarly, the Axiom of Extension says that if you make a version of set theory where sets can have the same elements but not be equal, then your set theory is not ZFC.

Comment: @JairTaylor is right: the Axiom of Extensionality is _not_ a definition of equality, it's merely a property that the membership relation satisfies. E.g. If you try to treat $a=b$ as a mere abbreviation of $\forall x. x \in a \leftrightarrow x \in b$, you won't be able to prove the universal closure of $(x=y \wedge x \in A) \rightarrow y \in A$.

Comment: So what you're saying the notion allows elements $a \in A$ to be equal to certain elements $b \in B$ is taken to be primitive? If we don't know how they can be equal, then aren't elements in some sense indistinguishable? 
Edit: Thanks for the responses. Brought some stuff that I should have been thinking about to my awareness.

Comment: You claim that in the set theory, "every mathematical object is set". This is not required, set elements need no be sets. Then you speak of *equal* elements. In fact, they are required to be *the same* element, which is a different thing.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't mean it to be so. I just meant that if we're going to use ZF as a foundation for mathematics we construct every mathematical object as a set? I've never come across an object within the framework that wasn't in some sense a set. Functions, operators, relations, numbers and so on. But I obviously don't think of them as sets. I'm aware it's not required, I just generally never see it treated as such which is my issue. 

I don't quite understand the distinction between 'the same' and 'equal' in this case.

Edit: I would give everyone an upvote but can't at the moment.

Comment: @Daedalus: in the case of objects defined from sets (essentially the empty set and set membership), equality is structural: the empty set is unique and two sets are equal if there is a bijection between equal elements.

Comment: That's quite a bit clearer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Isn't every element of a set in ZF itself a set? e.g., in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality#In_set_theory_with_ur-elements), "A ur-element is a member of a set that is not itself a set. In the Zermelo–Fraenkel axioms, there are no ur-elements, but they are included in some alternative axiomatisations of set theory."  The axiom of union wouldn't make sense if elements of sets were not themselves sets.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I still don't understand this distinction between "the same" and "equal".  What are two things in ZF that are not the same but not equal, or equal but not the same?

Comment: @JairTaylor The reason this question came to mind, was because instead of a typical visualization of sets with elements, I imagined a collection of 'dots' or vertices of a digraph on a piece of paper with no edges. Essentially, this could be represented by the set V. However, unless you label the vertices with different symbols, there's no way you can say any vertex is different from each other. It's only when you introduce edges, or more formally, 'relations', that you can make the distinction between the elements. That's why I was interested in a kind of 'individuals' notion of equality.

Comment: @JairTaylor Right now, I'm trying to find some kind of literature that takes 'elements' and 'functions/relations' as primitive notions. The best I can find is a paper that says it's possible to create equivalent axiomizations to ZFC using primitive notions other than set and element, but the details are tricky (and not referenced).

Comment: @Daedalus So you just want to define unlabeled objects? Usually that's done by defining by defining an equivalence relation (in this case, graph isomorphism, I assume) and then looking at the set of equivalence classes.  It might be possible to construct unlabeled objects in some other way, like a set of axioms, but that sounds more difficult, and you'd need to define each type of unlabeled structure separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any object is equal to itself, and only it can be equal to itself.  That's just how it is.

OK, you say, but what about the case where $a=d$?

Well, that just indicates that we use two different *labels* for the same one object.

OK, you say, but how would we know that $a=d$? Shouldn't we have a definition that spells out what equality_of_elements is before we can say that the-element-referred-to-by-$a$ is equal to the-element-referred-to-by-$d$?

No, we don't have such a definition. Equality is assumed. And there are no definitions that explicitly refer to the-way-we-refer-to-objects-using-different-labels. And finally, the fact that you would not *know* that $a=d$ is simply about just that: you just don't *know*. But it is still true. What you know and what is true is not the same thing.

But wait, you say, we aren't defining equality .. and yet we are defining equality of sets?! What gives?

Ah, well *that* is an interesting observation! Interestingly, there are 2 schools of thought on set equality.

Using the *extensional* view, two sets are said to be equal if and only if they contain the same elements. This is the typical way mathematicians look at set equality. As such, if $a=d$, $b=e$, and $c=f$, then $A = \{ a,b,c \} = \{d,e,f \} = B$. And again, just because we use two different labels $A$ and $B$ for these sets, does nt mean that the sets are different. In fact, if you *know* that $a=d$, $b=e$, and $c=f$, then you now also *know* that $A = B$. But even if you didn't know that, it would still be true.

OK, but there is also an *intensional* view on sets. This view says that sets are not solely defined in terms of their contents. We often informally think of sets as bags. So: think of two different 'bags', that happen to contain the same elements. On the extensional view, the two bags/sets must in fact be thew same one bag, but on the intensional view, they could still be different bags: while the contents are the same, the containers themselves are different.  Why might one hold such a weird view?  Well, here are two arguments for making such a move:

1. Consider the 'set of all people alive'. Clearly the contents of this set is going to change from day to day as people are dying or getting born. So ... everytime this happens, are we dealing with a different set?  The extensional view says yes. The intensional view says: no, it is still the same container .. but its content changes.  This mirrors a problem in philosophy of mind: are you still the same person when you lose a hair ro some cell in your body dies? You clearly went through a change ... and yet we also want to say that you are still the same person. In fact, the very notion of change only makes sense if there is the same one thing that goes through a change: the alternative is to say that things go in and out of existence every millisecond. Indeed, on the extensional view, you can't add elements to a set, because as soon as you do, you are dealing with a different set. The intensional view, however, will say that it is useful for to be able to think of adding things to a set just as we can add new things to a bag. Indeed, if we want to apply set theory to real life, where 'collections' do regularly change, then we may opt for a definition that can handle sets changing their contents.
2. As a continuation of the first point: Say I have a group of people in front of me, and I define two sets: the set of all people whose favorite sandwich is Peanut butter Jelly, and the set of all people born on a Tuesday. Now, it could of course so happen that these two sets completely coincide in terms of their contents. But this would be a fluke, of course. In fact, a new person (whose favorite sandwich is PBJ, but is born on a Wednesday) could walk in at any moment, and at that point the two sets will diverge. But the intensional view will say that the two sets were different the whole time: I was collecting different 'kinds' of things.

Anyway, to wrap up: on the intensional view, when we define 'set-equality' in terms of 'having the same elements', the intensional view says that that is not about 'equality of sets', but merely about 'equality of contents'. As such, even equality of sets is not defined, and hence any perceived inconsistency between 'we never define equality in math' vs 'we do define equality for sets' is resolved.

But even on the extensional view, you can regard the 'equality of sets' principle not as a definition, but rather as a truthful axiom: it is not that we define what *makes* two sets identical, but rather that it is simply true that identity of sets corresponds to identity of their elements.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. While my understanding of ZF increases with everyone's replies, I still find some troubles. My understanding now is this: ZF takes elements, sets and equality to be primitive concepts and constructs other concepts such as functions and relations. I've heard that the categorical theory of sets allows different primitive concepts to state an equivalent axiomization to ZF which constructs sets. Is it possible to have lets say, elements and functions as primitive and construct a suitable notion of equality?

Comment: I would also add: when I do actual exercises in ZF, I don't find any issues. It's when I think deeply about the axiomization that I run into troubles with how I want to think philosophically about what it's trying to convey. My primary goal (outside of the details of the question) is to ensure that while I'm writing mathematics (specifically algebra), I don't make any badly-formed statements. The explanation of intensional and extensional views was really helpful, since it'll allow me to go back and re-read stuff that I couldn't understand before.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, equality is assumed to exist already at the level of logic. Therefore the axiom of equality does *not* define the equality of sets, but it says that no two sets can have the same elements.

It's like when you say that different natural numbers have different prime factorizations. You don't define equality of natural numbers by their prime factorization, you just describe the fact that different natural numbers with the same prime factorization do not exist.

The only difference is that for natural numbers it is a property that you prove from the axioms, while for sets it is an axiom.

Said differently: The axiom does not say “if two sets have equal elements, we call them equal”, it says “There are no two different sets with the same elements.”

Answer (score 2):

> Only in the context of such a rule can we say the set {2+2,3+4} is
>   equal to the set {4,7}

It is true that if we were working with basic objects as primary elements, we would need an equality rule/ criterion specially for these objects. And this rule should precede the statement of the equality rule for sets.

But, in ZF set theory , any object is supposed to be itself a set.

***So, we do not need a further rule to  state that $2+2$ and $4$ are identical. We use the same rule for the identity of sets $A$ and $B$ and for the elements of $A$ and $B$, namely, the extensionnality principle***

I mean that, ***$2+2$ and $4$ are set themselves***, and the rule you will use to show that they are identical is the extensionnality axiom.

Using the construction of natural numbers and the definition of addition in terms of successor , you will end up with

$2+2= 2+S(1)=S(2+1)=S(3)= 3\cup \{3\} =\{0,1,2,3\}$

You also have, by definiton : $4=S(3) = \{0,1,2,3\}$.

The extensionnality axiom tells you that the two sets are identical.

---

I think your question is based on a couple of false assumptions regarding the universal quantifier and the meaning of the definiton of set equality. Maybe pointing out these assumptions could bring some clarification.

---

> ' Basically, we can say that $A=B$ if and only if for every $x\in A$ we have
>   $x \in B$  and for every $x\in B$ we have $x\in A$
>
> Now we are using $x$ as a symbol representing arbitrary elements of $A$
>   and $B$'

In the definition of set equality , more precisely in the " for all (x) " part, x is not supposed to stand for an element of A or of B. ***The variable $x$ stands for any object whatever.***

Consider this example. $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3\}$.

It is true that $\forall(x)\space ( x\in A \rightarrow x\in B)$.

> The reason it is true for all $x$ is that it is true, ***not only for all $x$
>   belonging to $A$ but also for all $x$ not belonging to $A$.***

Consider the case , say,  $x=5$. In that case $x\in A$ is false. So the conditional $x\in A \rightarrow x\in B$ is true for $x=5$ ( since its antecedent is false). And the same thing holds for any object not belonging to $A$. It would even be true for , say $x=$ The Eiffel Tower.

> 'In order for you to be able to say that $A$ and $B$ are equal, you have to
>   be able to provide some means through which you can say things like
>   $a=d$'.

It is true that *informally* we define set identity in terms of having identical elements. But in fact, ***technically, identity of elements is not used in the definition of set equality***. Rather, it is expressed in terms of reciprocal inclusion, which , itself, in analyzed in terms of conditionned membership.

***If set equality required identity of elements, no equality statement would hold for the empty set.***

Comment: Thanks for the example. I was being quite lazy with the notation, but it's an important point.

Comment: It is not simply a question of notation. What I wanted to point out is that in a $\forall(x)$ sentence, the sentence is really true for any $x$ whatever, ( in a given domain) not simply for the elements of the sets $A$ and $B$  under consideration.

Comment: When I say that  ' for all $x$ if x is english then $x$ is  british' , the sentence is true for any possible entity $x$  in the universe ( even the Sun, or the Eiffel Tower) , not only for those '$x$' that are actually english people.This can be explained by the truth table of the " if ... then " operator.

Comment: Absolutely. You were right to point it out, because I was using the wrong interpretation of the $\forall(x)$ sentence in my head. Until I get use to distinctions, I should probably be more rigorous and clear. I'm tempted to edit or re-write my question, since it seems to be more on understanding what it means for things to be equal in the first place and not necessarily about my misunderstanding of ZFC.

Comment: I think you will probably get interesting answers from set theory experts later in the day, so it can be useful to let the question as it is for the moment.

Comment: That's probably good advice.